# Theorist speculate about dozens of loud atmospheric booms across globe

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, seismic, air-currents

Theorist speculate on the dozens of loud [atmospheric booms](https://www.google.ca/amp/s/www.mnn.com/earth-matters/climate-weather/stories/amp/mysterious-loud-booms-are-being-heard-around-world-and-no-one-knows-why) across globe.  Has any recognized institutions offered a plausible explanation as of now?

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted (so I upvoted it for balance). Several reliable sources have mentioned these booms as well. Notes: 1) if you google around, you'll see this has happened previously, at least once a year between 2013 and 2016, and 2) the Leonid meteor shower may be producing an unusually high number of fireballs.

Comment: Having a few of those reputable sources, would  go a long way, not having any shows the OP has not put any effort into finding an answer themselves.

Comment: It's always going to be a very tough topic to answer when the proportion experiencing them likely means most physicists/atmospheric scientists/etc haven't personally heard them. And unlike some other rare phenomena like sprites or F5 tornadoes, there's no obvious pattern of audio structure or particular conditions found in (or detailed measurements of them). Plus the fact that most of us have at some point in life experienced peculiar sounds (or sights) and later discovered the cause was very reasonable may leave most scientists fairly skeptical that there's something special going on in them.